# How to Sort in Gridview using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to sort data by clicking one column header.in my code i use dataset to bind item.but i could not set the databind using javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In standard you can't sort the gridview with Javascript. But there are workarounds :

http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=106

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=2168345